# AJAX Request not receiving the property I want

Tags: javascript, html, object, syntax, console

I have to send an AJAX request to the following API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts. and then sort the result by the "title" attribute (ascending order) and print by console.log

The problem here is that I don't get the title attribute instead I get a lot of this:

[image: Website Example, AJAX REQUEST, button, fetch API]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Getting Started With Fetch API</h1>
        <button id="fetchJsonData">Fetch User Data</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById('fetchJsonData').addEventListener('click', fetchJson);

    function fetchJson(){
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
    }
    document.getElementById('fetchJsonData').addEventListener('click', fetchJson);
    
        function fetchJson(){
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(titles => {
                    let output = '<h2>Lists of Titles</h2>';
                    // output += '<ul>';
                    titles.forEach(function(titles) {
                        output += `
                            <li>
                                ${titles}
                            </li>
                        `;
                        output += '</ul>'
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = output;
                    });
                    
                });
        }

        function sortList(ul) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(ul);

  Array.from(ul.getElementsByTagName("LI"))
    .sort((a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent))
    .forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));
}

sortList("response");
        
</script>
</html>
```

Am I accesing the data the wrong way? please advice, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is an array of objects, you need to get the string vaule of the title if you want to render it directly.

```js
document.getElementById('fetchJsonData').addEventListener('click', fetchJson);

function fetchJson() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
}
document.getElementById('fetchJsonData').addEventListener('click', fetchJson);

function fetchJson() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(titles => {
      let output = '<h2>Lists of Titles</h2>';
      output += '<ul>';
      titles.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title)).forEach((obj) => {
        output += `<li>${obj.title}</li>`;
      });
      output += '</ul>';

      document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = output;
    });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Getting Started With Fetch API</h1>
  <button id="fetchJsonData">Fetch User Data</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the forEach loop, ${titles} should be ${titles.title}

Comment: Great! it was simpler than I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do this like this way.

Read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for more insight javascript.

```js
document.getElementById('fetchJsonData')
    .addEventListener('click', fetchJson);

function fetchJson(){
            fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(posts => {
                    let output = '<h2>Lists of Titles</h2>';
                    posts.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
                    posts.forEach(function(post) {
                        output += `
                            <li>
                                ${post.title}
                            </li>
                        `;
                        output += '</ul>'
                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = output;
                    });
                    
                });
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Getting Started With Fetch API</h1>
        <button id="fetchJsonData">Fetch User Data</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```